# Mock ImongoCollection driver 2.0.1 C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository, moq

I'm trying to write unit test for my repository layer that is using MongoDb 2.0.1 driver.

I have a dependency of ImongoCollection.

Someone knows how to mock that avoiding to use real db?
Thank you

Following is the code:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : Content
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _mongoCollection;
    public Repository(IMongoCollection<T> mongoCollection)
    {
        _mongoCollection = mongoCollection;
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        _mongoCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
    }

    public async void Update(T entity)
    {
        await _mongoCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
    }

    public async void Delete(string id)
    {
        await _mongoCollection.DeleteOneAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.Where(x => x.Id == id));
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(string id)
    {
        return await _mongoCollection.Find(Builders<T>.Filter.Where(x => x.Id == id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will retrieve a list of items 
    /// by passing a dynamic mongo query
    /// Eg. AND - var filter =  builder.Eq("cuisine", "Italian") & builder.Eq("address.zipcode", "10075");
    /// Eg. OR - var filter =  builder.Eq("cuisine", "Italian") | builder.Eq("address.zipcode", "10075");
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<List<T>> GetByFilter(FilterDefinition<T> filter)
    {
        filter = filter ?? new BsonDocument();
        return await _mongoCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    }


    public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _mongoCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm trying someting like

```
    private Mock<IMongoCollection<Content>> _mockContentCollection;
    private IRepository<Content> _contentRepository;

    [SetUp]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        _mockContentCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Content>>();
        _mockContentCollection.Setup(x => x.)....

        _contentRepository = new Repository<Content>(_mockContentCollection.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetAll_With_Results()
    {
        var a = _contentRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where do you have the problem exactly?

Comment: I don't see sense to write unit tests for repository and mock the key part of repository.

Comment: He is asking a way to mick the data using monogdb C# driver , in SQL Server we can seed , so he s looking for options like that @LzyPanda